# UICollctionView not loading Array Values in swift

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4

UICollectionView array values not loaded in cellForItemAt indexPath i am using following code

```
var tableData: [String] = ["Evo X", "458", "GTR"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collections", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
   let indexPath = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
   print("indexpath\(indexPath)")
   cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
   return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
       label.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
}
```

Array values are print in

> print("indexpath(indexPath)")

but not loaded in

> cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

my output is (console)

> print("indexpath(indexPath)")

```
indexpathEvo X
indexpath458
indexpathGTR
```

but This line get the error

> *cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]*

My error is

```
 Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can i fix that issue?

[image]

Comment: is CollectionViewCell has a textField/textView named celllabel???

Comment: CollectionViewCell have a label

Comment: Thankyou for your response

Comment: Please try indexPath.item instead indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

Issue

```
let indexPath = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
```

Solution

```
//let indexPath = self.tableData[indexPath.row] not needed
cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
```

**Explanation:**

You have a array of strings which you want to show in cell's celllabel component. You get the row from `indexPath.row` all you need to do is get the string at index `indexPath.row` hence

```
cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
```

is enough. Hope it helps

**EDIT 1:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collections", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
   cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
   cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
   return cell
}
```

Comment: I am already tried these line. but i am getting same issue. But command (//cell.celllabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]) these line i am getting output. when i select the "didSelectItemAt indexPath" display the values. but does not display the array values in collectionviewcell row

Comment: @ramkumar : Ill post the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath simply replace it with yours and lemme if it helps

Comment: @ramkumar : Use the cellForItemAt that I posted in EDIT 1 as it is and lemme know if it works

Comment: I am added my screenshot using simulator

Comment: @ramkumar : Implement func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { and return the size of cell to see the cell and the label

Comment: Thankyou sir but my problem is collectionview row not display the array values. i need to display the  Evo X, 458, GTR values in collectionViewCell Label

Comment: @ramkumar : From the screen shot I can see it loads 3 cell which is equal to number of strings in data source. So no issue with cellForItem at index path code. Now there might be two issues 1. Label/textField u added in collectionView cell does not have proper auto layout constraint hence going out side the frame of cell or 2.Cell's frame is so small that label not appearing hence I asked you to implement sizeForItemAt Add a background color to label/textField and check where it is in cell and provide some size to cell by implementing sizeForItemAt

Comment: Thankyou sir. I am checked these issues. but i cannot find the solution for this issue write now.